# Web Page Security Validation (Taxonomy AJAX Bug vs Silverlight Bug)

Tags: managed-metadata, web-application, taxonomy, silverlight, cumulative-update

The situation began like this:

1. We upgraded our SharePoint 2010 (using the Project Server 2010 February 2013 Cumulative Update)
2. We found a bug where on the 'Project Page' layout the 'Managed Metadata' field called 'Wiki Categories' will throw a HTTP 500 AJAX call to the TaxonomyInternalService -> GetMatches and GetSuggestions functions
3. A fix for this was to go to Central Admin -> Manage Web Apps -> General Settings -> Turn off Web Page Security Validation
4. But we have noticed now that the Site Settings -> More Option -> Create list, site etc. will throw a 'Silverlight Unhandled Exception'
5. The answer on the net to fixing this bug is to turn Web Page Security Validation 'On' which will re-introduce the Taxonomy AJAX issue.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix these issues or have experience in dealing with them?

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a resolution?

Comment: No, we have a call with Microsoft Premier Support but yet to receive feedback, were just lucky that Sites and Lists aren't created very often.

Comment: Any solution guys? I am also having the same issue.